# Java isn't recognizing my constructor

Tags: java

Java can't seem to find my constructor, I have no idea whats wrong. Is there a problem with having the throuws InterruptedException? Any Help would be appreciated, Thanks!

```
    package gameloop;

    import javax.swing.*;

    public class GameLoop extends JFrame {
        private boolean isRunning;
        public int drawx = 0;
        public int drawy = 0;

        public void GameLoop() throws InterruptedException{   
            setSize(700, 700);
            setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            setVisible(true);

            while(isRunning){
                doGameUpdate();
                render();
                Thread.sleep(1);
                if (isRunning){
                    GameLoop();
                }
            } 
        }

        private void doGameUpdate() {
            GameUpdate GU = new GameUpdate();
        }

        private void render() {
            Draw dr = new Draw();
        }

       public static void main(String[] args) {
            GameLoop GL = new GameLoop();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Remove the `void`. A constructor does not have a return type.

Comment: You should also move the update/render loop out of the constructor and into its own function, as well as remove the infinite recursion from the update/render loop.

Answer (score 6):

A constructor is named exactly like its class, and has no return type. If you provide a return type, even `void`, you create a method called `GameLoop`. What you are looking for is

```
public GameLoop()
```

rather than

```
public void GameLoop()
```

Answer (score 4):

You need `public GameLoop()`
constructors don't have return types

Comment: Thanks for the initial help! I got the window to show up, but now I'm getting new errors. In my Draw and Update Classes both of the line     "public class draw extends GameLoop" and "public class GameUpdate".

Comment: best to create a new question

Answer (score 4):

That's not a constructor - this is:

```
public GameLoop() throws InterruptedException
```

A constructor can not have a return type (`void` in your code), if you add one, Java will interpret it it as a normal method - even if it's called exactly like the class!

Answer (score 3):

You constructor has a return type so it is treated as any other method